# How to check if Visual Studio addin was called by pressing a shortcut combination?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I'm writing a little VS addin, which has a shortcut to it.
It calls the Exec method fine, but I don't see a way to figure out whether it was called using a shortcut, or clicking in Tools menu. I'm sure it's there somewhere, but the documentation is lacking..

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you need that? Why should the behaviour be different if it is executed via a shortcut? Just curious.

Comment: Plugin can do multiple things, I think having a direct access to them would be nice.

Comment: Although since only a single shortcut combination is displayed in Tools menu, this is not that useful, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and simply there is no simple way as of i know... and also according to normal practice and behavior addin should not behave differently. It should be independent of the way its executed.

Comment: However, plugin can have multiple shortcuts attached to it...  Making it a bug ?

Comment: ita not bug its a feature.. :)

Comment: Having no way of knowing is a pity indeed. I also wrote an add-in, it works when called from the Menu, but fails when called by a keyboard shortcut. I wish Visual Studio behavior were more consistent (and that the SDK gave more access to its functions).